# How to create videos similar to Khan-Academy videos with a Samsung Galaxy?

Tags: video, samsung-galaxy-note, samsung-galaxy-tab-2-10.1, samsung-galaxy-note-10.1

I would like to know what is the best option to create videos with audio similar to those of [Khan Academy](http://www.youtube.com/user/khanacademy) with Samsung Galaxy Tablets. Some of my colleagues have Samsung Galaxy 10.1 Note and some of them have Samsung Galaxy Tab. On the other hand, I have been able to create similar videos with audio using an iPad and the free ScreenChomp app (please see [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cjEMLLeur7Q)). The characteristics I like about the use of the iPad app ScreenChomp (and that my colleagues would like to have in a similar app for Samsung Galaxy Tablets) are:

1. It is easy to install (just find it in the app-store and download it)
2. I learned how to use it in five minutes
3. Once I finish a Khan-Academy-like video, I can upload it to the cloud (to a server of the ScreenChomp makers) and share the link by e-mail with my students, so they can see the video in their devices (laptops, tablets, smartphones, whatever) less than ten minutes after I created it
4. If I want to, I can download the video as MP4 in my laptop, so I am able to see it offline, and if I want, I can upload it to YouTube (which is Not necessary, as explained before, because students can see it directly from the link to the ScreenChomp site)
5. It is free.

I actually believed that the Samsung Galaxy Tablet would be a better tool to create this kind of videos (better than the iPad), however my student and I were unable to do it with a Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1, and my colleagues that received a Samsung Galaxy Note do not know yet how to do it. Could you let us know how to do it? We are interested in solutions as simple to use as the ScreenChomp in the iPad, as described in the five characteristics above. Is it possible in the Samsung Galaxy Tablets?

Comment: Without spending ages watching videos to work out what you're talking about, perhaps you could give a short description of what makes a video "Khan-Academy-like"?

Comment: Hello GAThrawn, it is very simple, I write in the screen with my finger or a stylus the solution to a Math or Physics exercise, step by step, and at the same time I am speaking and explaining the procedure. All of this is (writing and audio) is recorded, and immediately uploaded to a site, and I am given a link which I can e-mail to my students so they can see the video when they want and as many times as they like. If the video is five minutes long, I can complete the procedure in less than twenty minutes with Screenchomp. How to do something like that with Samsung Galaxy Tab or Note? Thks

Answer (score 1):

Here is how one teacher is using Coach's Eye for Android to create whiteboard style videos. Hope it helps! http://educationambassador.com/resources/entry/coachs-eye-app-is-elusive-android-flipping-whiteboard

Comment: Thanks for adding this to the conversation! In case this link breaks, can you edit your answer to include applicable quotes from the article, or maybe direct links to the Youtube videos?

Comment: @Mike That seems a great option! We will try it!

Comment: @Mike Well, I did buy and try using Coach's Eye in a Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1, as in the link you provided, Mike, but I have to say I am a bit dissapointed. It is very difficult to write properly any text, or even worst, any math symbol; I could not erase only one letter or symbol, have to erase everything; I finish the total space very fast and it doesn't have more pages or space that I can scroll down, so I have to erase everything in order to continue with the procedure. I will do some more experiments, but for the moment I have to say I do not recommend to use Coach's Eye this way